# DI + Generic repo + generic context + unit of work isn't work, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project where try to implement following technologies & patterns:

- Dependency injection based on Unity.MVC4
- Unit of work with generic repository & context
- Code first

But it's return an error:

```
The current type, JobParsing.Models.IContext`1[JobParsing.Models.Entities.Product], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

Code is following (sorry for a big amount of code, just for a concrete picture). Anybody know where is my mistake?

**Model:**

```
public class Product {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

**Entities:**

```
public class DbEntities : DbContext {
        public DbEntities() : base("DefaultConnection") {
        }

        public DbEntities(string connString)
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connString].ConnectionString;
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

**Context:**

```
public interface IContext<T> : IDisposable where T : class {
        DbContext DbContext { get; }
        IDbSet<T> DbSet { get; }
        DbEntities EntitiesForSp { get; }
    }

    public class GenContext<T> : IContext<T> where T : class {
        public GenContext() {
            DbContext = new DbEntities();
            DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
            EntitiesForSp = new DbEntities();
        }

        public GenContext(DbContext context) {
            DbContext = context;
            DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        #region IContext<T> Members

        public DbContext DbContext {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public DbEntities EntitiesForSp {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public IDbSet<T> DbSet {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        #endregion IContext<T> Members

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose() {
            if (this.DbContext != null) this.DbContext.Dispose();
        }

        #endregion IDisposable Members
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class {
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
        DbContext Context { get; }
        int Save();
    }

    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class {
        private IContext<TEntity> _context;

        public DbContext Context {
            get { return _context.DbContext; }
        }

        public GenericRepository() {
            _context = new GenContext<TEntity>();

        }
        public GenericRepository(IContext<TEntity> context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll() {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = this._context.DbContext.Set<TEntity>();
            return query;
        }

        public int Save() {
            return _context.DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing) {
                if (_context != null) {
                    _context.Dispose();
                    _context = null;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

**Unit of work:**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork {
        GenericRepository<Product> ProductRepository { get; }
    }

    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {
        protected string ConnectionString;
        private GenericRepository<Product> productRepository;

        public UnitOfWork(string connectionString) {
            this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public UnitOfWork(GenericRepository<Product> productRepository) {
            this.productRepository = productRepository;
        }

        public GenericRepository<Product> ProductRepository {
            get {
                if (this.productRepository == null) {
                    this.productRepository = new GenericRepository<Product>();
                }
                return productRepository;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Service:**

```
public interface IService {
        IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts();
    }

    public class Service : IService {
        private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

        public Service(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGenericRepository<Product> productRepository) {
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            //this.productRepository = productRepository;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts() {
            var movies = unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            return movies;
        }

    }
```

**Bootstrapper:**

```
public static class Bootstrapper {
        public static IUnityContainer Initialise(string connectionString) {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer(connectionString);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            return container;
        }

        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer(string connectionString) {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            // Register everything with Unity. A single line of code registers GenericRepository for all Entity types. 
            // Specific repositories, if defined, will also get registered here. 
            // Unity.MVC3 takes care of the MVC controllers so they are not registered here.
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(connectionString));
            container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
            container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();


            return container;
        }

        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container) {

        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
        private IService service;

        public HomeController(IService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        public ActionResult Products()
        {
            var genres = this.service.GetProducts().ToList();

            return View(genres);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line throws an error?

Comment: @Andrei When return to view. The last line which work correctly is in the  Global.asax.cs file Bootstrapper.Initialise("DefaultConnection");
            Database.SetInitializer<DbEntities>(new Initializer()); but after the last line I was saw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity uses the greediest constructor by default, so for your `GenericRepository` class it is using the constructor that takes an `IContext<T>`, which isn't registered in Unity.

You will need to either register `IContext` or to force the default constructor to be used as in:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>), new InjectionConstructor());
```

Comment: Exactly! I was mistaken at first, and when figured the actual problem your answer has arrived. Nice!